# Getters and Setters positions

Tags: java

It is alright to use constructors,getters,functions,methods and setters after the main function,to me this way is more confortable?

[image]

Comment: There is a standard, it is not about comfort. First you have to define the variables, then constructor and then all getter and setter methods.

Comment: @Sambit That's a *convention*, but it's not a hard requirement.

Comment: Yes chrylis Sir, it is a convention.

Comment: Paraschiv, on an entirely different note you need to read a basic tutorial on Java and pay attention to style. In Java, class names should start with a capital letter, and your getters/setters should be named like `getTitle`, not `get_title` (and this is actually an important technical requirement because lots of software reads these names automatically).

Answer (score 1):

You should create another class and put there `main` method. Class representing `anime` should be in different class. Also class should start with upper case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "hard rule" for how methods are ordered, but generally the variables are declared first, then constructors, then object methods with the getters and setters at the bottom.  This is part convention and part personal preference as I've seen it done many ways.  You should see java conventions: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html and generally try to stick to those.  You have quite a few naming convention Faux pas in your example... class name should be capitalized, method names should be camelCase, new lines between methods, etc.